# Is it possible to create an Azure VM with open port through Azure API?

Tags: azure

I am creating a VM using the following API:

> `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscription-id}}/resourceGroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{{vmName}}?api-version=2017-12-01`

Body:

```
{
  "location": "westus",
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "Standard_D1_v2"
    },
    "storageProfile": {
      "imageReference": {
        "sku": "2016-Datacenter",
        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "version": "latest",
        "offer": "WindowsServer"
      },
      "osDisk": {
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "managedDisk": {
          "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "name": "myVMosdisk",
        "createOption": "FromImage"
      }
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "adminUsername": "{your-username}",
      "computerName": "myVM",
      "adminPassword": "{your-password}"
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/{existing-nic-name}",
          "properties": {
            "primary": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I have to run a command to open a port to my VM:

```
az vm open-port --resource-group "my-rg" --name "my-vm" --port 3389
```

I was wondering if is it possible to include it in my json when I am sending the request, so I wouldn't need to perform the action to open a port through a command-line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is. Check [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-sshkey/azuredeploy.json) ARM template which creates a VM plus a network security group which has port 22 inbound open.

Just adjust this to your Windows VM. [Here is a sample template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json) for a Windows VM (without the NSG).

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented a nic creation with inbound open port and it worked.